# Vim: how to change phrase (of varied type and length) surroundings

Tags: regex, vim

I have a Rmarkdown file and I want to translate it to a media wiki file, because they are different markup languages, they have different syntax, and I want to find a way to change them all with the `substitute` command.

The two use cases are:

1. Change headings `# title`, `## subtitle` and the like to  `=title=` and `==subtitle==`,
2. Change surroundings `$inline formula$`, `$$standalone formula $$` and the like to `<math>inline formula</math>` and `:<math>standalone formula</math>`.

The two differ in that the first one I want to match the beginning of a  phrase, then surround it with some other symbols, and the second one is changing one kind of surrounding to another. I don't want to record some macros because the phrase can be very different, and there are many of them. I tried some commands like `%s/=*/*/gc` or `%s/$*$/<math>*</math>/gc` but they didn't work, so I think I might have messed up the regular expressions (my knowledge about regex is quite limited and I'm not sure which of the symbols should be escaped in Vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every regular expression dialect, `*` is a greedy quantifier that means "0 or more of the preceding atom, as many as possible", whereas it means "any character" when used as a glob (in your shell, for example).

Since substitutions in Vim use regular expressions and not globs, it should be evident why `:%s/=*/*/gc` and `%s/$*$/<math>*</math>/gc` don't do anything useful.

Another problem with your attempts is that you somehow expect the regular expression engine to guess what part of the match to reuse in the replacement. This is done by reusing "sub-expressions", sometimes called "capture groups".

See `:help \(`, `:help \1`, and http://vimregex.com/.

> 1. Change headings `#title`, `##subtitle` and the like to  `=title=` and `==subtitle==`,

```
:%s/^\(#\+\)\(.*\)/\=repeat('=',len(submatch(1))).submatch(2).repeat('=',len(submatch(1)))
```

Note that your markdown headings are malformed.

Comment: Thanks! How about the second one? I read the tutorial you gave and have managed to come up with `%s/\$\([^$]\+\)\$/<math>\1<\/math>` to change `$inline formula$` to `<math>inline formula</math>`, but unfortunately it also changes $$standalone formula $$ to `$<math>standalone formula</math>$`. And you are right I missed the spaces in headings.

Comment: I know I need some `lookaround` command but just can't get it right.. But never mind I've found a workaround: I first use `%s/\$\{2}\(.*\)\$\{2}/\:<math>\1<\/math>` to change all standalone equations, so that all double surroundings are removed; then just `%s/\$\(.\+\)\$/<math>\1<\/math>` to change all inline equations.